# Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument using stormpath

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, stormpath

I am using stormpath to sign up user from facebook authentication token. I am following the exact steps mentioned on stormpath wiki page http://docs.stormpath.com/java/product-guide/#integrating-with-facebook but i keep on getting below error.

HTTP 400, Stormpath 7200 (http://docs.stormpath.com/errors/7200): Stormpath was not able to complete the request to Facebook: this can be caused by either a bad Facebook directory configuration, or the provided account credentials are not valid. Facebook error message: **Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument**